# Matlab: Fit of histogram data with many Gaussians and AIC evaluation

Tags: matlab, statistics, curve-fitting

Consider this example of code to obtain the best fit from data varying the number of fitting Gaussians according the Akaike criterion

```
MU1 = [1];
SIGMA1 = [2];
MU2 = [-3];
SIGMA2 = [1 ];
X = [mvnrnd(MU1,SIGMA1,1000);mvnrnd(MU2,SIGMA2,1000)];
AIC = zeros(1,4);
obj = cell(1,4);
options = statset('Display','final');
for k = 1:4
 obj{k} = gmdistribution.fit(X,k,'Options',options);
 AIC(k)= obj{k}.AIC;
end
[minAIC,numComponents] = min(AIC)
```

I want to do the same thing but with data that are given in a form of a histogram (consider for example the data http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=1mNRuEHZ).

What is the most direct way to implement the same procedure in matlab in this case?

Comment: Why don't you just use the same algorithm, but instead of X use your histogram data?

Comment: @lhcgeneva That's my question! I don't know how to do it. If I just give X as the values of the histogram, it considers them as the extracted values not as the probability of the bin of the histogram.

Comment: How is it, that your 'histogram'-counts are not integers?

Comment: @lhcgeneva the data that I'm interested in are experimental data from light emission. Also the value outside the peaks is due to environment noise. I'm interested in the peaks above this noise, so an arbitrary value can be added to the histogram (in the example I have fixed it so that the average outside the peak is around zero - so it happens that there are negative values).

Comment: Right, so does the answer capture what you want to do? If not, I'm not getting the question...

Comment: @lhcgeneva Ok, I'm accepting your answer and open a new problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm getting you right, then your problem is to convert between data that is already compiled as a histogram (so numbers of observations paired with the actual value of an observation) and the original individual observations. Of course, when compiling the histogram, you have lost two things:

1. Order. You don't know what the order of observations was in the original data, which is probably not important, provided your observations are independent. Also, the way I get gmdistribution.fit() it doesn't take into account order anyway.
2. Resolution. When you create a histogram, you need to bin your data, which makes you lose precision, so to speak, because it is impossible to recover the precise values of your observations from the bins.

Once you are aware of that you can create a 'vector of observations' from your histogram data. Say, X1 is your histogram data (Nx2 vector). If you do

```
invX = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) repmat(y,1,x), abs(int16(1000*X1(:, 2)))', X1(:, 1)', ...
    'UniformOutput', false))';
```

you get a vector that contains individual observations, just like X in your example.

Note that you have to convert the bin counts to integers first. At this step, because the given data's precision is quite high, I had to round to make the computation possible for my machine. However, the final result seems fairly reasonable.

Also note that I used absolute values, there are some cases in your histogram data were your data is actually negative, which, for a histogram obviously doesn't make sense.

Last but not least you have to change the number of iterations for the fit procedure to 1000. The final code to produce the below figure reads

```
MU1 = [1];
SIGMA1 = [2];
MU2 = [-3];
SIGMA2 = [1 ];
X = [mvnrnd(MU1,SIGMA1,1000);mvnrnd(MU2,SIGMA2,1000)];
X = X1(:, 2);
invX = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) repmat(y,1,x), abs(int16(1000*X1(:, 2)))', X1(:, 1)', ...
    'UniformOutput', false))'; %'
X = invX;
AIC = zeros(1,4);
obj = cell(1,4);
options = statset('Display','final', 'MaxIter', 1000);
for k = 1:4
 obj{k} = gmdistribution.fit(X,k,'Options',options);
 AIC(k)= obj{k}.AIC;
end
[minAIC,numComponents] = min(AIC);

hold on;
plot(linspace(-1, 2, length(X1(:, 2))), abs(X1(:, 2)), 'LineWidth', 2)
plot(x, pd/max(pd)*double(max(abs(X1(:, 2)))), 'LineWidth', 5);
h = legend('Original data', 'PDF');
set(h,'FontSize',32);
```

Output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: this could be a possible solution but, as stated, it suffers of some limitations (in particular the loss of precision in the values in the histogram). But I see that it is a problem of how I asked the question. The best solution would be, I guess, to make a nonlinear fit for a function composed by a mixture of gaussians for the curve given by the histogram.

Comment: I'm changing the question to explain better (if the change is excessive, I could instead close this and open another - I'm not sure what's the right thing here).

Comment: Just ask a new question, the difference between the fit you mention now and using the above method is that the method used in this question also chooses which number of peaks to fit via the akaike information criterion. If you have less obvious data it might not be as clear how many peaks there are.

Comment: Just as a side note, the precision gain by using more data is a rather theoretical idea, I don't think it would change much in practice. Also, if you definitely want to use your data to the full extent a fit will be just as time consuming.

Comment: I still want to use the akaike criterion, this example is quite simple. I want to use the procedure also in case where the peak detection is quite less obvious.

Comment: So how would you go about implementing AIC? Cause that's too broad a question I think, the Matlab people came up with the gmdistribution class for a reason :P

Comment: you mean there is no AIC implemented in matlab for curve fitting?

Comment: There probably is, but you'll end up doing manually, what gmdistribution does for you anyway, I don't think there's a way to drastically reduce the time needed for the computation, unless you do a bit of rounding.

Comment: In the solution: X = X1(:, 2); the variable X1 is undefined

Comment: about 10 lines above in the text I defined X1 as 'Say, X1 is your histogram data (Nx2 vector).', It's essentially your histogram data in a two column vector, just like the one you linked to.